# Creating a legend in R with matching color and line shape

Tags: r, plot, graph, legend

How can I create a proper legend with the corresponding line type and color? Also, how can I create a Title for this graph?

In my legend, R corresponds to the solid black line, L is the dashed red line, and G is the green dotted line

Here is the code on how I created my graph and my legend:

```
matplot(x_values, cbind(r_y_values, l_y_values, g_y_values), type = 'l', xlab='N', ylab='Time(ms)')
legend("topleft", legend=c("R", "L", "G"), col=c(1:3), inset=0.01)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lty` and `col` arguments for the legend (you can find the different line types values here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/).
For the title, you can use the `main` argument.

```
## Plot
matplot(x_values, cbind(r_y_values, l_y_values, g_y_values), type = 'l', xlab='N', ylab='Time(ms)', main = "my title")
## Line type parameters
par_lty <- c(1,2,3)
## Line colours parameters
par_col <- c("black", "red", "green")
## Legend
legend("topleft", legend = c("R", "L", "G"), inset = 0.01, lty = par_lty, col = par_col)
```

Answer (score 7):

Just specify an lty value.

```
legend("topleft", legend=c("R", "L", "G"), col=c(1:3), lty=1:3, inset=0.01)
```